# How can I convert a compressed archive directly into a different format without fully decompressing the archive first?

Tags: compression, disk-space

I have a large, multi-GB archive in .zip format which I want to migrate to a better, more efficient format. The problem is that I don't have enough scratch space to hold the decompressed data (not to mention the original copy itself and the soon-to-be-made destination archive, which will all exist simultaneously at the end of the process). Is there a method or program that can decompress and recompress the file in memory and write out the destination archive without having to create the interim temp copy?

I'm on Windows, but answers applicable to Linux are fine too.

Comment: Out of curiosity - would it make a difference to re-compress the zip file into a different format straight away? (Similar to how tgz often made, tar, and gzip)

Comment: Interesting idea, but compressed formats don't compress again well, do they?

Comment: Make a RAMDisk (assuming you have enough RAM to hold all the uncompressed data), uncompress there, and re-compress from there?

Comment: The entire problem is that I'm low on space and am trying to save space. The archive in question is 30GB

Answer (score 0):

Although I dont think it is technically impossible to do, I dont believe there are any tools out there than can do this.  I was curious, so I did some research and couldnt find any tool that could accomplish this task.

If you dont have space on your drive, I would suggest you use a USB drive with decent capacity and do all the work there.  This would prevent your current drive from filling up.